# Wpf - Update custom user control at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

hey guys i created an wpf application with custom usercontrol , the problem is that i am unable to update or say change the properties of custom control at runtime, 
-->heres a code of user control
File:usercontrol.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExampleWpf.UserControlExample"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

          Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
<Rectangle Width="60" Height="200" Fill="#FFB65959" Name="Box1"></Rectangle>
```

File:usercontrol.xaml.cs

```
namespace ExampleWpf{
public partial class UserControlExample : UserControl
{
    public UserControlExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public double Box1Width
    {
        get { return (Box1.Width); }
        set { Box1.Width = value; }
    }
}
```

--->Heres a simple code for Wpfapplication
File:Mainwindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControlExample uc = new UserControlExample();
        uc.Box1Width = 100;

    }
}
```

All i wanted to change the width of a custom control at run time when user click on the button----> but unfortunately i doesn't succeed
please help me out

Comment: i just wonder.. can you show xaml code Button too?

Comment: there you go-->
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="370,275,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a **new instance** of your user control and not doing anything with it.

You should be finding the **existing instance** of the control and updating that.

You should also implement this type of behaviour through [Dependency Properites](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html). This gives you all sorts of advantages as outlined in the tutorial, but the main one here is that you can set properties like this at runtime.

Comment: is  it possible by calling the ~Destructor of the last instance and call again the IntializeComponent() method?

Comment: then how could i find the existing instance of the Control?

Comment: @MasterOpti - either name it (as in Florian's answer) or you have to search the visual hierarchy for it.

Comment: Problem Solved Heres the solution 
For UserControl.xaml file i bind the Rectangle width property to Box1Width method from UserControl.xaml.cs file-->    

`<Rectangle Width="{Binding Path=Box1Width}" Height="200" Fill="#FFB65959" Name="Box1"/>`

and i also make changes to WpfApplication.xaml file    
`<Box:UserControlExample x:Name="uc"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use the instance you placed in your xaml (f.e. through the Name-property), like so:

```
<uc:UserControlExample Name="myUC"/>

myUC.Box1Width = 100;
```

Another problem could be, that you just change the Width of the UC's rectangle. So lets say the UC has a Width of 50 and you call uc.Box1Width=100, the UC has still a Width of 50, so it wont change anything.

Comment: then what about ActualWidth?

Comment: You cant set ActualWidth. Just set the Width of the UC itself through this.Width = value; and make sure the rectangle stretches with `Stretch = Fill`